# Perform Action to all possible combinations of columns

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, contingency

I´m new to R so forgive me if the question is quite mundane.
I have a table with categorical variables as columns. I need to calculate the contingency coefficient between every possible combination of two columns.

To calculate the contingency coefficient I use `ContCoef()` from the `DescTools`.
`ContCoef()` expects two columns as inputs.

```
ContCoef(data[,1], data[,2], correct = TRUE)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(data)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) The website of the `DescTools` package lists the `PairApply` function. So something similar to `PairApply(data, ContCoef, symmetric = TRUE)` could work. But again hard to tell without an minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using `PairApply`:

```
library(DescTools)
PairApply(comp_testdata,FUN=function(x,y) cor(as.numeric(x),as.numeric(y),method='pearson'),symmetric=TRUE)
```